# set one output high at a time when multiple inputs are high

Tags: transistors, current

I'm making a small circuit for detect water level of our home water tank .here is the diagram.

[image]

when water level is low i want to turn red led when water level is max i want to turn green one on and so on.but current circuit turn both red/yellow/green when water level is max because when water level high all terminals sink .

how can i turn only one led instead of all .for example when all terminals are sunk i want to turn only green led. how to turn only one led instead of all ?

Comment: That's a truly horrific circuit, by the way. Not only are no current limiting resistors as shown, as Wouter notes, but it passes DC through the electrodes so they'll be chemically etched away. It has the advantage of being much simpler than anything decent.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany can you clarify "they'll be chemically etched away"

Comment: See[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroetching) reference, for example.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks but do all probes/metals etch.i thought some metals doesn't etch on the water when Electrolysis

Comment: At very least, I would consider implementing float switches instead of using the resistor sensing setup you have.

Comment: @stefandz reason plz ??i have see lot of this kind of circuits on internet .my first attempt was floating mechanical switches.is there any side effect of this circuit ?

Comment: For the same reason that @SpehroPefhany noted - the electrodes will get chemically etched away. The reason there are so many circuits like this out there is that they are simple to understand and educationally informative - but they are not robust long-term solutions. One more interesting method might be using an ultrasonic sensor to detect the liquid level, or even capacitive level sensing from outside the main container.

Comment: @stefandz thanks much but will every electrodes will get chemically etched away?for example aluminum ? i will ask this on chemistry stack-exchange thanks all .may be i have to use floating switches

Comment: On a long enough timeline the survival rates for all electrodes will drop to zero. Aluminium will decay relatively rapidly because it is quite a reactive metal and its protective oxide (which gives us the general illusion of it being inert) will be electrolytically removed in any case. Gold or platinum plated or electrodes will last longer, but eventually they will all corrode.

Comment: Not all electrodes will be etched away. Carbon is a good (and cheap) choice.

Comment: downvoters and born to downvoters leave a comment ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have series resistors in your circuit that you left out in your picture? Otherwise you are pushing an undetermined amount of current through the transistors and LEDs.

To 'block' a lower LED you could use this basic circuit (untested):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkmPtm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As others have stated in the comments, if you use copper electrodes they will over time dissolve. How fast depends on the current, which you can minimize for instance by using darlington transistors and higher values for the base resistors.

But not all electrodes will be etched away, only those that can be oxidized easier than the abundantly available H+/H3O+. This includes copper, but not platinum or (cheaper and more readily available) carbon.

Comment: Nice (and simple) idea. Would R3 be connected to the highest or lowest probe? Need to have think about this one - something in the back of my head is saying it won't give a single LED output.

Comment: @wouter van ooijen i didn't left resisters .that's my entire circuit i'm using 3v dc power.is there any problem in this circuit ?

Comment: Had a think - and by my reckoning R3 goes to high probe, R4 to mid and the last one (not shown) goes to low. Then it will need another diode (D5) from the third stage (low) back to the collector of Q1 so that when the high stage is turned ON it will pull both the mid **and** low stages down.

Comment: You won't need that extra diode, when Q1 is active Q2 will be active too, and Q2 will disable the lowest LED.